# Keeping a fragment saved when activity is destroyed and reuse it later again

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a feature that requires me to keep the fragment (all of user's interactions saved in the same order) when the user decides to exit the activity to browse the app but with an option to go back to the same activity/fragment (without any change to the UI or interactions), the catch is it's an external SDK and I don't have access to the views inside the fragment to save them individually so what I'm thinking is maybe there's a way to save the exact same fragment maybe in sharedPreferences and reuse it once the activity is re-launched but I'm not sure if that works so does it work and how? and if not is there another way to make this happen?
Here's how I'm saving the fragment:

```
private fun saveFrag(frag: Fragment) {
    val editor = sharedPrefs.edit()
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = gson.toJson(frag)
    editor.putString("hello", json)
    editor.apply()
}
```

and

```
private fun getFrag(): Fragment {
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = sharedPrefs.getString("hello", "")
    return gson.fromJson(json, Fragment::class.java)
}
```

Also the above implementation is giving this exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView declares multiple JSON fields named

Comment: You can’t restore Fragments this way. Surely the SDK should provide some way to get info out of its views and restore initial data, right?

Comment: After digging in it for over 3 weeks I found that it can be saved in a janky way using roomdb and some listeners that weren't even in their documentation, made me question my life choices.